# Core Date - Predicate for filtering dates

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have a CD entity that has a date attribute. When I am doing my fetchrequest I pass this predicate on to it:

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(eventStartDate >=%@) AND (eventStartDate <=%@)", startOfDay, endOfDay];
```

These are the dates I am passing:

```
First Date:2015-07-10 00:00:00 +0000

Second Date:2015-07-10 11:59:59 +0000
```

I know there is one item that matches this query (starts after midnight today but before 11:59:59 today) but it is not being returned by the predicate. If I rewrite it with an OR conditional, it returns all the previous dates. If I just have the greater than condition then current and all future dates are returned. How can I write this so I just get items that match today's date?

Thanks

Here is how I am formatting secondDate. I did have 11 instead of 23 for :

```
NSDate* today = [[NSDate alloc] init];

NSCalendar* currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
[currentCalendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];

NSDateComponents* dateComponents = [currentCalendar components:NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:today];

NSInteger thisMonth = [dateComponents month];
NSInteger thisDay = [dateComponents day];
NSInteger thisYear = [dateComponents year];

NSDateComponents* endOdDayComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[endOdDayComponents setDay:thisDay];
[endOdDayComponents setMonth:thisMonth];
[endOdDayComponents setYear:thisYear];
[endOdDayComponents setHour:11];
[endOdDayComponents setMinute:59];
[endOdDayComponents setSecond:59];

return [currentCalendar dateFromComponents:endOdDayComponents];
```

Comment: Are you sure that the date you wand is really between these two? I'm thinking about a possible issue with a zone issue. It could be 11:59:59 +1100 or -1100 (never known which sign is correct to break the test) for example.

Comment: Also Second Date looks to be (just before) midday, not midnight.

Comment: See my edits. The time zone is GMT.

Comment: endOdDayComponents contains a date 1 second before noon in your current timezone. clearly not end of day.

Comment: Could you show the log of the date that you're trying to find?

Comment: The log printout of the dates is in the original post.

Comment: vikinggoesgundo - even if I change the hour to 23 the predicate still does not work.